# Interact with redis container started with docker compose

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file that links my server to a redis image:

```
version: '3'

services:
    api:
        build: .
        command: npm run dev
        environment: 
            NODE_ENV: development
        volumes:
            - .:/home/node/code
            - /home/node/code/node_modules
            - /home/node/code/build/Release
        ports: 
            - "1389:1389"
        depends_on: 
            - redis

    redis:
        image: redis:alpine
```

I am wondering how could I open a `redis-cli` against the Redis container started by `docker-compose` to directly modify ke/value pairs. I tried with `docker attach` but it does not open any shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `docker exec -it your_container_name /bin/bash` to enter into redis container, then execute `redis-cli` to modify `key-value` pair.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 1):

Install the Redis CLI on your host.  Edit the YAML file to publish Redis's port

```
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:alpine
        ports: ["6379:6379"]
```

Then run `docker-compose up` to redeploy the container, and you can run `redis-cli` from the host without needing to directly interact with Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Using `/bin/bash` as the command (as suggested in the accepted solution) doesn't work for me with the latest `redis:alpine` image on Linux.

Instead, this worked:

```
docker exec -it your_container_name redis-cli
```